# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n} = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show the above problem I already write in the title by using the following equality:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^n}{n} = \infty$ if $a>1$.

I tried to solve this problem by seeing the sequence as a function. But, I want to know by only seeing sequences. Please help!

Comment: Do you mean "if $a\gt1$"?

Comment: right. I have a mistake

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Set $a=e$ and $n=\log(m)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have ${{log(a^n)}\over {a^n}}= {n\over{a^n}}log(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler than that:  prove that for all $x\ge 1$, $\ln x<2\sqrt x$.